# How Do you convert JQuery HighChart to React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, highcharts, react-hooks

Here is a full link to the project: [Electoral Map](https://jsfiddle.net/OBrian/z3q7xcga/15/)
I have this Highchart map that I'm trying to convert to React but can't quite figure it out. I tried using React rappers but didn't succeed.

What I have:

JSON data - will be fetched from an API but I have hard-coded them as below.
Jquery functions that maps the data.
Several highcharts imports.

I have not included the path data, too long it wouldnt post.

```js
    $(function() {
      var json = [{
        "name": "Busia",
        "registered": "251305",
        "UDA": "0",
        "Azimio": "0",
        "value": "-5"
      },{
        "name": "Wajir",
        "registered": "118091",
        "UDA": "8",
        "Azimio": "7",
        "value": "-2"
      }]

      function init() {

        function pointClick(json) {
          var row = this.options.row,
            $div = $('<div></div>')
            .dialog({
              title: ([this.name]),
              width: 400,
              height: 300
            });

          window.chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
              renderTo: $div[0],
              type: 'pie',
              width: 370,
              height: 240
            },
            title: {
              text: null
            },
            series: [{
              name: 'Votes',
              data: [{
                name: 'Azimio',
                color: '#0200D0',
                y: Number(this.Azimio)
              }, {
                name: 'UDA',
                color: '#C40401',
                y: Number(this.UDA)
              }],
              dataLabels: {
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b> {point.value:.1f}%'
              }
            }]
          });
        }

        // Initiate the chart
        $('#presidential').highcharts('Map', {
          title: {
            text: 'Presidential Electoral Map <em>(Kenya)</em>'
          },
          legend: {
            title: {
              text: 'Political Affiliation' 
            }
          },
          credits: {
            enabled: false
          },
          tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: 'Margin'
          },
          mapNavigation: {
            enabled: true,
            enableButtons: false
          },

          colorAxis: {

            dataClasses: [{
              from: 0.0000001,
              to: 100,
              color: '#C40401',
              name: 'UDA'
            }, {
              from: -100,
              to: -0.00000001,
              color: '#0200D0',
              name: 'Azimio'
            }, {
              from: 0,
              to: 0,
              color: '#C0C0C0',
              name: 'Battle Ground(s)'
            }]
          },
          series: [{
            name: 'By County Difference',
            point: {
              events: {
                click: pointClick
              }
            },
            "type": "map",
            "joinBy": ['name', 'name'],
            "data": $.each(json, function() {}),
            "mapData": [{
              "name": "Busia",
              "path": "M40,-534,43,-533,46,-532L46,-530L44,-528,44,-525C44,-525,41,-520,41,-520L40,-516,40,-513,41,-511C41,-511,44,-512,43,-509,43,-506,44,-504,44,-504L38,-499,38,-497,44,-495,45,-493,41,-489,41,-486L36,-486L34,-487,30,-488,28,-487,25,-484,22,-484,20,-486,18,-483,16,-481,15,-478,14,-476L14,-473L15,-471,14,-469L12,-469L10,-467,9,-464,10,-459C10,-459,9,-458,7,-457,5,-456,5,-455,5,-455L3,-459,0,-462,0,-465,2,-470,2,-474L2,-478L5,-481,8,-486,10,-491,13,-493L13,-495L12,-499,13,-503,15,-506,15,-510,16,-513C16,-513,19,-516,20,-517,21,-517,24,-519,24,-519L27,-519,28,-519,31,-520L31,-524L32,-526,33,-527,34,-531,35,-532z"
            },
            }]
          }, {
            "type": "mapline",
            "data": [{
              "name": "path5072",
              "path": "M443,-449Z"
            }]
          }]
        });
      }
      init()
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I've reproduced your example in the working demo that you can find below.

What's important, I didn't use the dialog popup which is a specific jQuery method. Instead, I show a pie chart inside the tooltip, with the use of several `point.events` such like `mouseOver`, `mouseOut` and `click` as well.

```
    point: {
      events: {
        //Show the default tooltip
        mouseOver: function () {
          let point = this;
          this.series.chart.update({
            tooltip: {
              enabled: true,
              formatter: function () {
                let s = "";
                s += `<span style="color:${point.color}">●</span> <span style="font-size: 10px"> ${point.series.name}</span><br/>`;
                s += `${point.name}: ${point.value}<br/>`;
                return s;
              }
            }
          });
        },
        //Show the pie chart
        click: function () {
          let y1 = Number(this.Azimio);
          let y2 = Number(this.UDA);
          this.series.chart.update({
            tooltip: {
              useHTML: true,
              enabled: true,
              formatter: function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                  Highcharts.chart("chart", {
                    chart: {
                      type: "pie"
                    },
                    title: {
                      text: null
                    },
                    series: [
                      {
                        name: "Votes",
                        data: [
                          {
                            name: "Azimio",
                            color: "#0200D0",
                            y: y1
                          },
                          {
                            name: "UDA",
                            color: "#C40401",
                            y: y2
                          }
                        ],
                        dataLabels: {
                          format: "<b>{point.name}</b> {point.value:.1f}%"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  });
                }, 10);
                return '<div id="chart" style="width: 300px; height: 150px;"></div>';
              }
            }
          });
        },
        //Remove the tooltip
        mouseOut: function () {
          this.series.chart.update({
            tooltip: {
              enabled: false
            }
          });
        }
      }
    },
```

**API REference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.map.point.events

**Demo:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-44tmqt